# Identify order based on coordinates

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I would like to map coordinates (,) to a particular order ID, which will help me track when the coordinates changes.

I need a formula which gets a specific ID based on coordinates.

Here are a few examples for coordinates:

```
00-1
10-2
01-3
11-4
02-5
12-6
03-7
13-8
04-9
14-10
05-11
15-12
```

I can use map of these values, but not sure how big this could grow.

Unable to identify the formula to get order when coordinates are passed.

Could someone identify the logic here..

Thanks

Comment: Looks like `1+x+2*y` to me

Comment: It seems to be `1 + firstDigit + (2 * secondDigit)`. I'm not sure if this question belongs to SO.

Comment: I dont think that 1+x+2*y will work cause (1,3) will result the same as (5,1). Please clarify why
`a.toString+"-"+b.toString()`
 (exactly like you did) does not work for you

Comment: @dismedia probably there is no `5,1`. The first digit is always `1` or `0`, so I assume there will be just 20 coordinates. Anyway, you're correct, OP should be more clear.

Comment: Yes there will be no 5,1 as coords will be either starign with 1 or 0

Comment: How could I determine the reverse of this, like if i pass 8 i need 13 etc..

Answer (score 1):

Here are two functions for both directions:

```js
const toId = (x, y) => 1 + x + 2*y;
const toCoord = (id) => [--id % 2, id >> 1];

// Demo:
for (let id = 1; id < 16; id++) {
    let [x, y] = toCoord(id);
    let id2 = toId(x, y);
    console.log(id + " to coordinates: [" + x + "," + y + "] ...and back to id: " + id2);
}
```